# HP DAT 160 not compressing data

Tags: backup, hp

I have an extenal HP DAT 160 USB.
The system i use is a Windows Server 2003, i launch a backup over the device with NTBackup.
I cannot store in the dat more than 80 GB, that is the hardware compression seems not to work.

Comment: Perhaps your data isn't compressible.

Comment: Was about to say just the same thing Tom - @AgostinoX, have you tried zipping this data you're backing up? this'll tell you how compressible it is. Oh and have you considered just using a portable hard disk for this, it won't last as long but it'll be much quicker and have more capacity.

Comment: i thought that hc had not to do with software compression, does it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure your system is using hardware compression.

NTBackup had a bug in the early W2003 editions that disabled hardware compression by default. Microsoft has a [support note and hotfix for this behavior](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827475).